# Ionic 4 with angular 7, Cannot find type definition file for '@types'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-aot

I upgraded my ionic 4 project to use angular 7, everything works on debug mode, but when I try to compile for production:
'ionic cordova build android --prod', I am getting the following output:

> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android
>   [20:24:15]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4 
>   ...
>   [20:24:44]  typescript error 
>               Cannot find type definition file for '@types'.
>
> [20:24:44]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
>   [20:24:44]  Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript 
>   Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript
>       at errorCheckProgram (/Users/jesusotero/Projects/Bambuco/confiar/mardeconfianza/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:119:39)
>       at Object. (/Users/jesusotero/Projects/Bambuco/confiar/mardeconfianza/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:89:21)
>       at step (/Users/jesusotero/Projects/Bambuco/confiar/mardeconfianza/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
>       at Object.next (/Users/jesusotero/Projects/Bambuco/confiar/mardeconfianza/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
>       at fulfilled (/Users/jesusotero/Projects/Bambuco/confiar/mardeconfianza/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
>
> ionic-app-scripts build --prod --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.

I have not been able to find any solution out there to this problem so if anybody there can put me in the right direction on how to solve this problem I really appreciate it.
My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "author": "xxxxxx",
  "homepage": "xxxxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.15",
    "@ionic-native/android-full-screen": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/mobile-accessibility": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.6",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": "^1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.11.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.11.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Answer (score 2):

based on the data you shared your project is Ionic 3 project (3.9.6).

Ionic 3 was not meant to be used with Angular 6+.

I would suggest check Ionic 3 reference app’s package.json and downgrade your dependencies accordingly.

[Reference App v3 branch](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/tree/v3)

Answer (score 2):

ionic-app-script was recently updated producing this error.

As a workaround, you can lock its version in your package.json to the last working one:

"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3"

or downgrade it

Comment: well, not recently but for those who coding with ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

Solution: serve your project with `ionic serve` and then update any .ts file in src folder and save it (ctrl+s) and it will automatically build again and serve the app & error will be resolved, hopefully :).

This solved my issue.

Referred from instructions that were posted on ionic framework forum.